# NGinx - muliple SSL domains, single .conf file

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have the need to support blah.domain1.com and blah.domain2.com in the same configuration file under SSL.  I have wildcard SSL certs for *.domain1.com and *.domain2.com (this is a multi-tenant server).

What are my options here, since this (of course) won't work:

```
    server_name blah.domain1.com blah.domain2.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain2.key;
```

Do I need to clone the .conf and reference each domain and SSL certificate separately, or is there something else I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are many ways to accomplish this, but this is what I do:

In `nginx.conf` include the following line in the `http` block:

```
include .../nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

The `sites-enabled` directory contains symlinks to conf files for each domain.

Then use `.../nginx/sites-available/` for the symlinks to point to. This way you can manage unique conf files for each domain.

`...nginx/sites-available/example.com`:

```
server {
    <configuration>
}
```

`...nginx/sites-available/example.net`:

```
server {
    <configuration>
}
```

When you want example.com to be available for nginx to serve, just run:

```
# ln -s .../nginx/sites-available/example.com .../nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
# service nginx restart
```

I prefer this method because looking at really long conf files confuses me.